# Is there a way to use transform scale to make content auto-fit in a parent div?

Tags: css

Consider this:

[image]

With an exact number for scaling the content (`transform: scale(0.62);`) we can achieve this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this scaling without using a precise number? The content would be changeable so it has to work for any content.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/PoPXqbQ?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

/*
.content {
  transform: scale(0.62);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasda
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfs
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdas
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: Is the height and width set on that yellow box? If so, you could use `calc` to calculate the `scale` value...

Comment: @HereticMonkey The width and height of the content would be changeable though...

Comment: Simply no it is not...JS is required, CSS can't detect the size of a container., nor does is know the size of the content

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way with only clear CSS. Made a scale script for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let containerW = $('.container').outerWidth(),
      containerH = $('.container').outerHeight(),
      contentW = $('.content').outerWidth(),
      contentH = $('.content').outerHeight();
  
    if ((containerW - contentW) < (containerH - contentH)) {
      let ratio = containerW / contentW;
      $('.content').css({'transform' : 'scale('+ratio+')'});

    }  else {
      let ratio = containerH / contentH;
      $('.content').css({'transform' : 'scale('+ratio+')'});

    } 
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasda
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfs
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdasd
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdas
    sdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdsdfdsfsdfsdfasdfsdfasdasdasdas
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you try it? The solution is flexible, adapts for any content inside.

Answer (score 0):

This would need help of Javascript too. Get the widths and heights of **container** div and **content** div in Javascript. And then the below trick might help :

```
scale = min( 
  availableWidth / contentWidth, 
  availableHeight / contentHeight 
);
```